# Insert (or append) a line ending with a trailing backslash (\) using sed

Tags: linux, sed

On Linux (BusyBox, QNAP-NAS) I want to add some extra path to my `.bashrc` file via script using sed. The relevant part of the file looks as follows:

```
[...]
export PATH=\
/bin:\
/sbin:\
/usr/bin:\
/usr/sbin:\
/usr/local/bin
[...]
```

The extra line to be inserted (at position 4 in the original file) is `/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:\`. To get this done my sed one-liner looks like this:

```
sed '4i/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:\\' .bashrc > .bashrc.tmp
```

, correctly escaping the trailing backslash. Somehow sed converts the remaining `\'` into a newline eating up the trailing backslash, resulting in:

```
[...]
export PATH=\
/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:

/bin:\
[...]
```

Adding a third backslash gives me the trailing backslash, but still adds the newline, so

```
sed '4i/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:\\\' .bashrc > .bashrc.tmp
```

results into

```
export PATH=\
/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:\

/bin:\
```

If I add an extra space in my sed command

```
sed '4i/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:\\ ' .bashrc > .bashrc.tmp
```

everything looks fine, but I get the extra space at the end of line as well.

```
export PATH=\
/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:\  # extra space here

/bin:\
```

What did the trick for now is a second sed command removing the trailing spaces

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -e '4i/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:\\ ' .bashrc > .bashrc.tmp
sed -e 's/[ \t]*$//' .bashrc.tmp > .bashrc.tmp2  # change \t to real tab
```

But still I wonder why sed is transforming `\'` into a newline, and how to solve the above job with a simple one-liner? How can I insert (or append) a line with a trailing backslash using sed?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

```
sed '4s|^|/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:\\\n|' .bashrc
```

Comment: christoph, you can accept the answer by clicking on the "tick".

Answer (score 1):

If of any help I used four backslashes to append a backslash without space at the ond of a line.

My command looks like this:

```
sed "1i #backtrace_script\n#!/bin/sh\ngeany -si \\\\" \
```

which results in

```
 #!/bin/sh
 geany -si \
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in busybox sed.  It works fine with GNU sed 4.2.1.

Comment: Oh, I should have checked that in the first place. It works fine with my Debian/Ubuntu and GNU sed 4.2.1. as well, so there is a bug in BusyBox sed. I could now stick with my two-liner, but I like the workaround from Dennis better.